# Passing PHP array through JSOn for output in Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am working on a jQuery script that retrieves a PHP array from MySQL database and returns it as a JSON object.
This all works correctly and I can output the raw JSON object, including the key.

The issue I am having is the way I am outputting it, which I currently do using jQuery's $.each.

Example: (Not the full script, just what is needed)

```
                if(data){
                $.each(data, function(key, data) {
                $('#div').append(  key + ' : '  + data  );

                });

        }

    } , 'json')
```

So at the moment the output is like so: Example

```
     Name: Tom Age: 20 Gender: Male
```

However I don't want all results of the array to be returned, which is what $.each is doing.
I want to manually output different parts of the array, where and when I want.

I tried something like this so that I could just get the array result that has the Key of "name" but it did not work (one of my array keys is name):

```
    $('#div').append(  key + ' : '  + data['name']  );
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Making it a bit more clear:

Rather than looping through and outputting the entire array I want to output only select parts: e.g;

data.name
data.age

Those for example will only output the 2 arrays with the name and age key, even if the array has 10 other results.

Array we are working with is like so, only 1 result, but with multiple values.:

```
    {Name: 'Tom' Age: 20 Gender: 'Male'}
```

Comment: `console.log(data)` and copy paste the console's output here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
$.each(data, function(key, data) {
    $('#div #span-'+key).html(data);
});
```

So if you have the keys name, age, gender, you need 3 spans with the ID: #span-name, #span-age, #span-gender and they will be filled in with the data. If you only need name and age, just delete your #span-gender span and it won't show.

Your html will be something like:

```
<div id="div">
    <span id="span-name"></span>
    <span id="span-age"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats pretty much what I am looking for.
Now I am able to select particular array results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
   $('#div').html(key + ' : '  + val.name);
});
```

**suggestion:**
use `.html()` it will let you to update the div with latest results `.append()` will append the result with previous results.

Answer (score 0):

Use different variable names in the `each` . You are using `data` as the main object as well as second argument of callback. Also note that use of keys is case sensitive

Change the second to something else

```
$.each(data, function(key, item) {
                $('#div').append( item.Name  )
```

ALso not clear what your data looks like. I am assuming it is an array of objects like:

```
[ {Name: 'Tom' Age: 20 Gender: 'Male'}, {Name: 'Jane' Age: 20 Gender: 'Female'}]
```

If the data is only a single object only, and no array, you don't need to use `$.each` and just access the object directly using object notations

```
{Name: 'Tom' Age: 20 Gender: 'Male'}
alert( data.Name);
```

Comment: Right that. Unless and until we know how the array looks like, no luck in any solutions

Comment: The issue with that though is it still outputs all other results as undefined.

Comment: @JPDP no idea what you are talking about

Comment: I would do that, but I want to grab and output just the Name and Age at one point in the script and then gender at a later part in the script, without alerting as they will be added to a table.

Comment: `alert()` is simply a demo. Not sure what your data even looks like to help further

Answer (score -1):

In your jQuery code, do this.

```
if(data){
    var dec_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data[0]);
    //Loop over it now
    jQuery.each(dec_data, function(key, val){
        //Stick it in the div
        jQuery('div').append(key+' - '+val);
    });
}
```

Comment: Try it before you downvote! You're already `json_encoding` it, but you're not decoding it on jQuery side.

Comment: OP is trying to parse data that already exists in javascript, what does `json_encode` have to do with it?

Comment: Not encode, but decode on the jQuery side does have a lot to do with it.

Comment: Doing that provides the following Firebug error:
"TypeError: e is null"

Although from the looks of it that wont accomplish what I need, that still looks like it loops through and displays the entire array, rather than letting me select the parts I want.

Comment: Can you post the raw array over here? Because all of the answers assume your array is like this: `Array( key1 => val1, key2 => val2...)`. If its not like this, then the above solutions will fail.

Comment: Array is like so:

[ {Name: 'Tom' Age: 20 Gender: 'Male'} ]

Comment: Since you're putting the json object in another array and then returning it, you need to access the 0th index in the array.